# Use AJAX to send array of JavaScript objects to database

Tags: c#, jquery, sql-server, ajax

In this project the user will have the opportunity to create an array of objects with properties and those properties match up with a database table, with the properties of the object being the same as the columns in the database cable.  The SQL looks like:

```
create table ServiceData
(ServiceId int
,ServiceDescription varchar(50)
)
go
create type ServiceType as table
(ServiceId int
,ServiceDescription varchar(50)
)
go
create proc spInsertService
@service ServiceType readonly
as
begin
    insert into ServiceData(ServiceId,ServiceDescription)
    select * from @service
end
```

Here I create a custom type and pass that custom type to a stored procedure in the form of a table valued parameter.  The SQL and the following C# code execute and work fine:

```
[WebMethod]
        public void InsertServiceData()
        {
            List<ServiceData> sdList = new List<ServiceData>();
            ServiceData sd1 = new ServiceData(1, "first");
            ServiceData sd2 = new ServiceData(2, "second");
            sdList.Add(sd1);
            sdList.Add(sd2);
            DataTable dt = new DataTable();
            dt.Columns.Add("ServiceId");
            dt.Columns.Add("ServiceDescription");
            foreach (var data in sdList)
            {
                dt.Rows.Add(data.ServiceId, data.ServiceDescription);
            }
            string cs = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["dbcs"].ConnectionString;
            using (var con = new SqlConnection(cs))
            {
                using (var cmd = new SqlCommand("spInsertService",con))
                {
                    con.Open();
                    cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@service", dt);
                    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
                }
            }
        }
```

You can see that in this working example I'm not using any AJAX call to send data to the web method.  This code currently works and inserts the data from that hardcoded list fine.  So when I change the code to actually try to take a JavaScript array like so:

```
 $(document).ready(function ()
        {
            sd1 = {};
            sd1.ServiceId = 1;
            sd1.ServiceDescription = "test";

            sd2 = {};
            sd2.ServiceId = 2;
            sd2.ServiceDescription = "other test";
            //create array which is meant to mirror the List<ServiceData> in the 
            //earlier example
            service = new Array();
            service.push(sd1);
            service.push(sd2);
            //wrap the array in a data transfer object
            var dto = {'sdList': service};
            $('#btnSubmit').click(function ()
            {
                $.ajax(
                {
                    type: "POST",
                    url: "WebService.asmx/InsertServiceData",
                    contentType: "application/json",
                    dataType: "json",
                    //stringify the dto
                    data: JSON.stringify(dto),
                    success: function(data)
                    {
                        console.log('success');
                    },
                    error: function(thrownError)
                    {
                        console.log(thrownError);
                    }
                });
            });
        });
```

new C#

```
[WebMethod]
        //this attempts to deserialize the DTO into a list of ServiceData objects
        //which are then inserted into the TVP and then to the database

        public void InsertServiceData(string sdList)
        {
            var jss = new JavaScriptSerializer();
            List<ServiceData> list = jss.Deserialize<List<ServiceData>>(sdList);
            DataTable dt = new DataTable();
            dt.Columns.Add("ServiceId");
            dt.Columns.Add("ServiceDescription");
            foreach (var data in list)
            {
                dt.Rows.Add(data.ServiceId, data.ServiceDescription);
            }
            string cs = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["dbcs"].ConnectionString;
            using (var con = new SqlConnection(cs))
            {
                using (var cmd = new SqlCommand("spInsertService",con))
                {
                    con.Open();
                    cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@service", dt);
                    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
                }
            }
        }
```

Currently that code gives me the error: `Type\u0027System.String\u0027isnotsupportedfordeserializationofanarray`
If I don't wrap the array in a DTO object, but still stringify it I get

```
`System.Collections.Generic.IDictionary`2[[System.String,mscorlib,Version=4.0.0.0,Culture=neutral,PublicKeyToken`
```

I would like to not have to use SessionState of ViewState for this.  Since I know the code works fine if I'm not passing a JavaScript array to the WebMethod, it has to been somewhere in the serialization and deserialization of the array that's breaking it.  How can I fix this? It's been driving me nuts for days now

Comment: I'd suggest you don't `JSON.stringify(dto),` your data. Send the dto  and define a matching class for the WebMethod to accept, or use a dynamic.

Comment: When I try that I get the error: `{"Message":"InvalidJSONprimitive:undefined."`

Answer (score 0):

> Please note following steps and then change your code lines.

1. Dont create `sd1={}` and `sd2{}`.
2. Create `var list = [];` at top then push json object like `list.push({"ServiceId":1,"ServiceDescription":"test"},  {"ServiceId":2,"ServiceDescription":"other test"})`
3. Create ajax parameter like `var data = "{'sdLists':" +JSON.stringify(list)+"}";` and pass date as param.
4. Create a bean with variables to map json object as added in list above. see blow.

   public class SdList{
   private int Serviceid;
   public int Serviceid
       {
         get { return Serviceid; }
         set { Serviceid= value; }
       }
   private string ServiceDescription;
   public string ServiceDescription
       {
         get { return ServiceDescription; }
         set { ServiceDescription= value; }
       }
   }
5. Now Pass `List<SdList> sdLists` as parameter list to method as under

   var data = "{'sdLists':"+JSON.stringify(list)+"}";
   public void InsertServiceData(List sdLists)
6. Then Convert Json List in to generic list  using java script serializer as under,
   `JavaScriptSerializer jss= new JavaScriptSerializer();`

   `List<SdList> list = jss.ConvertToType<List<SdList>>(sdLists);`

I have followed above steps and it is working fine.